# Counting the number of passwords of length 6 with the given conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

A password of length 6 with upper case letters, lower case letters and digits. Password must contain at least 1 upper case, 1 lower case and 1 digit. How many possible passwords are there ?

What I did. Total are $62^{6}$.

Passwords in which upper and lower are mixed(no digits) = $ 52^{6} - 2(26^{6})$.

Passwords in which upper and digits are mixed(no lower) = $ 36^{6} - 10^{6} - 26^{6}$.

Passwords in which lower and digits are mixed(no upper) = $ 36^{6} - 10^{6} - 26^{6}$.

I subtracted all these from the total so get $ 62^{6} - 52^{6} - 2(36^{6}) + 2(26^{6}) + 10^{6}$.
Is this the correct way.

What other ways could one think about ?

Comment: Your answer is correct but your working is missing details. You have correctly found all passwords with only two of them (LU, UD, DL) and subtracted. Then you also need to subtract passwords with only U, L or D which you seem to be doing but you have not written that anywhere in your working.

Comment: They are in the cases. For example 36 ^6 has already all digit passwords etc

Comment: take digits and lowercase for example. When you subtract $10^6$ and $26^6$ from $36^6$, it gives you passwords that are made of both digits and lowercases. You subtract it from $62^6$ and similarly others. What about subtracting passwords which are made of only digits?

Comment: See your math. Based on what you have written, in the final expression, you should have $+ 4 \cdot 26^4$ but you have only $+ 2 \cdot 26^4$.

Comment: I want to count those which we dont need.

Comment: So those which have upper and lower = $52^{6}$ those which have upper and digits and those which have lower and digits each $36^{6}$  but in the first I count only upper and lower too. In the second only upper and digits and in the third only lower and digits. Since I count them twice i add them at the end

Comment: That is correct but you have not explained it and you straightaway add, leading to confusion. That is what my first comment said that you have not added details behind it.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked my final answer with that of the OP: are answers match.  I simply had some trouble following the OP's logic, so I arrived at the same answer by a moderately different route:

Also, the alternative to Inclusion-Exclusion, which I will briefly describe, but do not advise using, would be a **direct** approach:

The number of digits used will either be $1,2,3,$ or $4$.
In each of the 4 cases, you then have to enumerate how many of the remaining characters are uppercase vs lower case.

As an illustration:
In the case of 3 digits used, you will either have 1 uppercase or 2 uppercase.  Exploring the specific case of 3 digits, 2 uppercase, and 1 lowercase, the enumeration would be:

There is $A = \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{5}{2}$ ways of positioning the digits, uppercase letters and lowercase letters.

Then, once the positions are set, there are $B = (10)^3 \times (26)^2 \times (26)^1$ different character assignments that can go in the corresponding positions in the password.

Therefore, the enumeration for this subcase is $A \times B.$

There may be a more elegant approach for the **direct** approach alternative to Inclusion Exclusion that is escaping me.

Anyway, in any event, Inclusion-Exclusion is much easier.

---

From [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

Let $T_k$ denote the number of ways that **at least** $k$ constraints are violated.

Then, you want $T_0 - T_1 + T_2 - T_3.$

$T_0 = (62)^6.$

To calculate $T_1$, there are 3 possibilities:
No uppercase, no lowercase, or no digits.

Therefore,
$T_1 = (36)^6 + (36)^6 + (52)^6.$

To calculate $T_2$, there are 3 possibilities:
No uppercase or lowercase, no uppercase or digits, no lowercase or digits.

Therefore
$T_2 = (10)^6 + (26)^6 + (26)^6.$

In considering $T_3$, it is impossible for all three constraints to be violated, because no characters are allowed except the 62 letters/numbers.  The assumption that all 3 constraints are violated would mean that there were no characters available.

Therefore
$T_3 = 0.$